# Access of undefined property myItem

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new in as3 and flex and there is probably a dump question. The following code raises an error  Access of undefined property myItem. But why? All variables are accessable and defined. Do i register this variable somewhere else? I can not just define a new variable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        var myList:Array = new Array();
        var myItem:int = 12;

        myList.push(myItem);
        trace(myList);

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Comment: This should work (also tested it to be sure). How are you programming? Are you using seperate classes (Document class) or are you using the timeline to do programming?

Comment: Just made a new project with flash builder 4.5.1 added the code in <fx:Script> part. Perhaps my installation is damaged.

Comment: have you addet it in some function? or just pure?

Comment: just pure :( and reinstal Flash Builder 4.5.1 don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to be in a function in order for you to reference your declared variables. You can put

```
myList.push(myItem);
```

and

```
trace(myList);
```

in a function and call that function on *creationComplete* or *preInitialize* if you want to run it right away. Or if you absolutely want to initialize myList with the value 12, just declare it like

```
var myList:Array = [12];
```

and get rid of myItem altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I was just to stupid. That happens if one just flick through some introductions and think that one can build space ships with that knowledge -.-